# Non-homogenous linear recurrence relation reasonable TRIAL solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

From my book Discrete Mathematics by Rosen, I came across an explanation that confused me a bit

**The question was:**

Find all solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = 3a_{n−1} + 2n$. What is the solution with $a_1 = 3$?

**And the part of the explanation that confused me was:**

"We now find a particular solution. Because $F(n) = 2n$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree one, a reasonable trial solution is a linear function in $n$, say, $p_n = cn + d$, where c and d are constants."

I can't seem to figure out why they chose $cn+d$ as a trial solution for $f(n) = 2n$, why this very specific choice?

Comment: See also: [Form a general formula to find the $n$th term of a recursive function given by $A_n = 3A_{n−1} + 2n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2683021) and [Recurrence relation: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n, a_0 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2684316).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because $F(n) = 2n$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree one, a reasonable trial solution is a linear function in $n$

Given $F$ is a polynomial, it makes sense to look for particular solutions in polynomial form, and it is reasonable to start with the lowest degree that could possibly work, which is the degree of $F$.

Note that there is no guarantee that a particular solution exists in this form, in which case you'd bump the degree up by $1$ and try with a quadratic.

( A linear solution does in fact exist in the given case, but for example if you change the recursion to $\color{red}{3}a_n = 3a_{n−1} + 2n\,$, then the solution requires a quadratic. )