# Form a general formula to find the $n$th term of a recursive function given by $A_n = 3A_{n−1} + 2n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Here is the recursive formula: $A_n = 3A_{n−1} + 2n$. Given that when $A_0 = 1$, how can I generate a general formula to get $n$th term? Instead of working out term one by one until I get to the $n$th term.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit your question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Can you solve a similar simpler problem?

Comment: i tried to list down the answer from n=1 to n=10 one by one and get them as 1, 5,19,63 ,197... but i couldn't figure a way to represent them in one general formula to get Nth term.

Comment: See also: [Non-homogenous linear recurrence relation reasonable TRIAL solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559352) and [Recurrence relation: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n, a_0 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2684316)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose,
more generally,
$a_n
= ua_{n-1}+vc_n
$.

We can get rid of the $u$
by dividing by $u^n$.

The recurrence becomes
$\dfrac{a_n}{u^n}
= \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{u^{n-1}}+\dfrac{vc_n}{u^n}
$.
If we let
$b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{u^n}$,
this is
$b_n
=b_{n-1}+\dfrac{vc_n}{u^n}
$
or
$b_n-b_{n-1}
=\dfrac{vc_n}{u^n}
$.

Summing from $1$ to $m$,
this becomes
$\sum_{n=1}^m(b_n-b_{n-1})
=\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{vc_n}{u^n}
$
or
$b_m
=b_0+v\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{c_n}{u^n}
$.

Putting in
the definition of $b_m$,
$\dfrac{a_m}{u^m}
=a_0+v\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{c_n}{u^n}
$
or
$a_m
=a_0u^m+vu^m\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{c_n}{u^n}
$.

In your case,
with $3 = 2, v=2$
and $c_n=n$,
this becomes
$a_m
=a_03^m+2\cdot 3^m\sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{n}{3^n}
$.

Hint for that last sum:
look at
$\sum_{n=1}^m nx^n
$.
The cases $x=1$ and
$x \ne 1$
need to be handled
separately.