# Recurrence relation: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n, a_0 = 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Solve the following recurrence relation by generating its direct
>   formula: $$a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n, a_0 = 1$$
>   Use the direct formula to find the
>   $10th$ term of the recurrence relation.

My attempt:

$3(10-1) + 2(10)$

$3(9) +  20$

$27 + 20$

$10th$ term = $47$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think, you mean: $a_n=3a_{n−1}+2n$

Comment: `My attempt` You are calculating $3(n-1)+2n$ for $n=10$, but that's not $a_{10}$.

Comment: Your attempt indicates you are confused as to how recurrence relations work.  Does $$a_0=1\implies a_1=3a_0+2\cdot1=3\cdot1+2=5$$ make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $3^n$ and define $u_n=a_n/3^n$. Solve the resulting equation for $u_n$ (this involves computing a sum) and retrieve $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

For a linear difference equation we break the problem up into $2$ parts: find the general solution to the homogeneous equation and then add any particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation to get the general solution. For the homogeneous equation
$$a_{h,n}-3a_{h,n-1}=0$$
Take the general solution to be $a_{h,n}=C\cdot r^n$. Then
$$C\cdot r^n-3C\cdot r^{n-1}=C\cdot r^{n-1}(r-3)=0$$
So $r=3$. For the inhomogeneous equatio we hope for a solution of the form $a_{p,n}=An+B$. Then
$$a_{p,n}=An+B=3a_{p,n-1}+2n=3\left(A(n-1)+B\right)+2n=3An-3A+3B+2n$$
So $-2An=2n$ therefore $A=-1$ and $3A=-3=2B$ so $B=-\frac32$ and our general solution is
$$a_n=a_{h,n}+a_{p,n}=C\cdot3^n-n-\frac32$$
The initial condition is
$$a_0=C-\frac32=1$$
So $C=\frac52$ and the solution to the initial value problem is
$$a_n=\frac52\cdot3^n-n-\frac32$$
This agrees with the first few iterates of [@FoobazJohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2684416).

Answer (score 0):

We have $$a_n=3a_{n-1}+2n\implies a_{n+1}=3a_n+2(n+1)\implies a_{n+2}=3^2a_n+3^1\cdot2(n+1)+2(n+2)$$ so we see that $$a_{n+k}=3^ka_n+2\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^i(n+k-i)$$ Hence substituting $n=0, k=10$ gives $$a_{10}=3^{10}a_0+2\sum_{i=0}^93^i(9-i)$$ Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1}=3a_n+2(n+1) $$
$$a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}+2 (n+2)$$

thus
$$a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}+3a_n=2$$

the characteristic equation is
$$x^2-4x+3=0$$
the roots are
$$x_1=1\;\;x_2=3$$
$$a_n=A+B.3^n+\alpha n$$

$$a_0=1 \implies A+B=1$$
$$a_1=5\implies A+3B+\alpha=5$$
$$a_2=19\implies A+9B+2\alpha=19$$

thus
$$2B+\alpha=4$$
and
$$6B+\alpha=14$$

$$B=\frac {5}{2} \;\;A=-\frac {3}{2}$$
Finally
$$B=5/2 \; A=-3/2 \;\;\alpha=-1$$
$$a_n=\frac {5}{2}3^n-\frac {3}{2}-n $$

Comment: Doesn't look like a hint to me...

Comment: It's also… wrong? $n=2$ gives the wrong answer (correct: $19$; yours: $17$.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Is it fine now

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of a problem that can be solved with generating functions. By manipulating the recurrence, you should find that the generating function for the sequence $(a_n)$ is $$f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \frac{-3 x^3+6 x^2-5 x}{(x-1)^2 (3 x-1)}$$
whose $x^n$ coefficient is not *toooo* painful to extract.

Comment: This is ok but a bit overkill imho

Answer (score -1):

The recurrence is 
$$
a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n \tag{1}
$$
for $n\geq1$ where $a_0=1$ .
If you want to compute using the recurrence relation only (as your post indicates), note that in order to find $a_{10}$ we need the value of $a_9$ and thus the value of $a_8,a_7,\dotsc, a_1$. To begin equation (1) implies that
$$
a_1=3a_0+2(1)=3(1)+2(1)=5
$$
and thus using equation (1) again
$$
a_2=3a_1+2(2)=3(5)+2(2)=19
$$
Proceed in a similar fashion to compute $a_3,\dotsc, a_9$ and finally $a_{10}$.

Comment: OP asked for a direct formula

Comment: OP attempt's indicates  that he tried to use the recurrence.