# Recurrence relation question (generating direct formula)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Solve this recurrence relation by generating its direct
>   formula: $$a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2n, a_0 = 1$$
>   Using the direct formula find the
>   $10th$ term of this recurrence relation.

My answer:

$a_{10} = 147601$ [image: Reasoning:]

Is this correct?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684316/recurrence-relation-a-n-3a-n-1-2n-a-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Please use MathJax, images are unwidely.

Answer (score 2):

You have not produced the required direct formula.

*Hint*

> Note that $a_{n} + n = 3 a_{n-1} + 3 n = 3(a_{n-1} + n) = 3(a_{n-1} + n-1) + 3$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but after I solve it my recurrence relationship is 3^n + 26n. 
so I sub n = 10 in and I obtain 59309.

Comment: I don't get that answer. I get the solution $$a_n=\frac {5}{2}\cdot 3^n-\frac {3}{2}-n $$ Which gives $a_{10}=147611$, which almost agrees with the OP's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct. Note:
$$a_{10}=3a_9+2\cdot 10=3\cdot 49197+20=147611.$$
However, can you find $a_{10}$ directly, that is without finding $a_1,a_2,...,a_9$? You will need a formula for it. There are several methods to find the general formula:
$$a_n=\frac52 \cdot 3^n-n-\frac32 \Rightarrow a_{10}=\frac52\cdot 3^{10}-10-\frac32=147611.$$